# How does "addActionListener(e->{..})" work? Is it better than an ActionListener?

Tags: java, events, java-8, actionlistener

I was watching tutorials of Bucky Roberts from theNewBoston about JavaFX and suddenly he typed this line of code `button.addActionListener(e->{System.out.print("Button Clicked");});`. I want to know what this ***e->*** is **called**. I've tried it on my simple GUI program and it works.

Is it **better** than using **actionPerformed()** method? Are there also statements like this on other listeners?

Comment: It's the same and it's better just because it's shorter.  When you say it this way it's called a lambda expression.  New in java 8.

Comment: Bucky Roberts is tidbit blurry in all of his tutorials. You should follow a book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know what this e-> is called

It is called a [Lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and was added to Java 8 a year ago.

> Is it better than using actionPerformed() method?

You are using an `actionPerformed` method.  This is just a short hand way of writing it.

It is better if this results in simpler/clearer code, and often it does (but not always)

> Are there also statements like this on other listeners?

Yes. Any interface with exactly one abstract method can be written this way.